# Ignoring fork-bomb in Ubuntu

Tags: process, ulimit, fork

I got an homework assignment to write a program that checks how many process a user can create (working in Ubuntu). I wrote the code which seems fine in theory. The problem is that when I run it, the system closes it and doesn't allow it to run after 3-5 seconds of work. The only reason I could think of is a protection embedded in Ubuntu. Is there a way to ignore this and run my program? I tried running it with root permissions as well but no luck.

How my program works: The 1st process fork() a new one and the father is put in wait to his son, then the newly created process creates another process (fork again) and waits for it and so on, until fork() fails and then I print a counter. Then everything existing so no zombies are left.

Comment: You really shouldn't edit your question like you did. Either delete it yourself or (even better) share your answer for future visitors.

Comment: Change your algorithm (print "Process number [N] forking...") -- When the process table is full (or your program is killed) the last value of [N] printed is the limit. (or look at `ulimit` / `/etc/security/limits.conf` & see what the value is :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, you're likely hitting a defined `nproc` limit. The [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) for it describes the limits contained within. This is likely what's killing your attempted forkbombing.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into `ulimit -a`. On my system (Ubuntu 12.04), it gives:

> $ ulimit -a
>   core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
>   data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
>   scheduling priority             (-e) 0
>   file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
>   pending signals                 (-i) 29951
>   max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
>   max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
>   open files                      (-n) 1024
>   pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
>   POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
>   real-time priority              (-r) 0
>   stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
>   cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
>   max user processes              (-u) 29951
>   virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
>   file locks                      (-x) unlimited

When you look at "max user processes" (`ulimit -u`), you will see, that I can create at most 29951 processes.